# Excepción [Array to String conversion]

Tags: symfony2, doctrine, dql

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto en `Symfony 2.8`, y lo que intento hacer es realizar una consulta usando `doctrine` que me sume lo valores de una columna de una tabla y me envíe el total a mi `página.html.twig`.

Aquí el código que he escrito en la clase controladora donde quiero realizar dicha operación:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query_ganancia = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT SUM(v.ingresos)
            FROM CarroBundle:Viaje v
        ');

        $var_ganancia = $query_ganancia->getResult();


        return $this->render('CarroBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('ganancia'=> $var_ganancia));
    }
}
```

Y en la página obtengo el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
<h1>{{ ganancia }}</h1>
```

Pero por algún motivo que aún no veo me sigue devolviendo esta **excepción**:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in CarroBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 39.
```

He buscando la guía de Symfony 2.8 referente a `Doctrine` e intenté realizar la operación de ésta otra forma sin resultado:

```
$var_ganancia = $query_ganancia->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Me gustaría alguien me orientara sobre este error. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que realizar un tratamiento array a la variable ganancia en Twig:

```
{% for ganancias in ganancia  %}
<h1>{{ ganancias }}</h1> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Eso ha funcionado!! Pero me queda la duda de por que la necesidad de realizar el tratamiendo array a la variable ganancia, si en el controlador le estoy diciendo que me devuelva un solo resultado.

Comment: La variable que defines como ganancia lleva asociado un query a bbdd, considerado como array. En este caso un array de un solo elemento.